# Replication of only updates and inserts

Tags: sql-server-2016, transactional-replication

I have two sql servers, in the first I want to keep the data from the last three months and in the second I want to keep all the data with the purpose of getting historical reports.
I know how to do a transactional replica but I don't know how to replicate only the inserts and updates, I don't want to replicate the deletions.

Is it possible to do this with replication between servers or do you have to program it yourself through triggers?

Comment: Maybe a scheduled job fits better

Comment: I just want to know if the replication between servers can only of updates and inserts, without taking into account the deletions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Article Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/view-and-modify-article-properties?view=sql-server-ver15), you can set the publication to not replicate deletes.

On the Article Properties page, just scroll down to `Delete delivery format` and change it to "Do not replicate..."

Note that if you're not replicating deletes, you risk a scenario where a row or update errors and causes issues. This will only happen if a deleted row has a value that is reused on the primary key or other unique constraint. If you're using an `IDENTITY` column for PK (and no other unique indexes on the replicated data), this would only happen only if the ID is reseeded or someone uses `IDENTITY_INSERT`. It's a more common problem to encounter when using a [natural key](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5431/surrogate-key-vs-natural-key-differences-and-when-to-use-in-sql-server/). If you anticipate this being a problem, you can put [`instead of` triggers](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/09/sql-plan/instead-of-triggers) on the replicated copy to convert inserts to [upserts](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern)

[image: Article Properties]

Comment: Thank you very much
I'm not sure if sql server reuses the guid type keys when removing the old ones.